# Begin new captureSession without removing previewLayer

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I'm creating a customView for the CameraView, which works fine however i'm now working on changing from the back camera to the front camera. i've at the moment done it by doing below. However this seem to create a bad user experience where it removes the previewLayer (the screen becomes white) and then show the front camera correctly. is there a way to create a better user experience by not making everything white in 1 sec before showing the new session?

**switchCamera**

```
func switchCamera() {
    if usingbackCamera == true {
        endSession()
        beginSession(frontCamera!)
        usingbackCamera = false
        self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(actionView)

    } else {
        endSession()
        beginSession(backCamera!)
        usingbackCamera = true
        self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(actionView)
    }
}
```

**beginSession**

```
func beginSession(device: AVCaptureDevice) {

    do {
        captureSession.addInput(try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))
        self.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

        previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
        captureSession.startRunning()

        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
        }



    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

**endSession**

```
func endSession() {
    self.previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

}
```

**Take Picture**

```
func takePicture() {


    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in


                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

                let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                self.previewImageView.image = image
                self.previewImageView.hidden = false
                self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(self.previewImageView)





        })
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to stop the captureSession and start it again when switching from back to front camera and vice versa.

All you need to do is remove the old capture session inputs, add the new one and all that in between a begin/commit session configuration block.

Here is a rough example:

```
  func switchCamera() {
    //begin configuration changes
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    //remove the previous inputs
    let inputs = captureSession.inputs as! [AVCaptureInput]
    for oldInput:AVCaptureInput in inputs {
        captureSession.removeInput(oldInput)
    }

    //add the new input
    if usingbackCamera == true {
        addInput(frontCamera!)
        usingbackCamera = false
        self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(actionView)

    }
    else {
        addInput(backCamera!)
        usingbackCamera = true
        self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(actionView)
    }

    //end the configuration
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}


func addInput(device: AVCaptureDevice) {

    do {
        captureSession.addInput(try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))

    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: endConfiguration is no a member of captureSession

Comment: Correct @PeterPik , it should be `commitConfiguration`, was typing directly here without using Xcode and I forgot that it's `commitConfiguration` and not `endConfiguration`

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to remove the preview layer when changing the input device.
The layer is bond to the session, all you have to do is stop the session, remove the original input and add the new input then start the session again.

I make my capture view by custom rendering, but I thought the process will be the same.

The capture snippet:

```
    for output in session.outputs {
        if let capture = output as? AVCaptureStillImageOutput{
            for connection in (capture.connections as! [AVCaptureConnection]){
                for port in (connection.inputPorts as! [AVCaptureInputPort]){
                    if port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo{
                        capture.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connection, completionHandler: {(buffer, err) -> Void in
                            if err != nil{
                                print(err)
                            }
                            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
                            guard let image = CIImage(data: imageData) else{
                                completion(nil)
                                return
                            }
                            let rotatedImage = image.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2)))
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is good however after switching camera the takePicture returns `NULL sample buffer.'`

Comment: You mean the sampleBuffer is null or the imageData?

Comment: I change my mind, here is my real suggestion again. Find the output from session.outputs but not from the instance of stillImageOutput you declared

Comment: Could u provide a snippet as a answer, im not sure what you mean?